# In regards of using Math.pow method, and its precision

Tags: javascript, math, pow

This may be a noob question to ask. It is about `Math.pow` in JavaScript.

```
var amount = 0.55;
var decimal = 18;
var value = amount * Math.pow(10, decimal);

console.log('amount: ' + amount + ' value: ' + value);
```

If the amount is 0.55,I expected the returned value to be `550000000000000000`.

But, instead it returns `550000000000000060`

If the amount is 0.56,I expected the returned value to be `560000000000000000`.

But, instead it returns `560000000000000060`

**How do I get the expected returned value and why does it happen?**

Comment: What's `decimal` in your code? You haven't defined it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh,,,my bad I will edit it now.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

Comment: @T.J Crowder I see why it is happnening now. It is because JavaScript treats decimals as floating point numbers, it is subjecting to rounding error. Thank you!

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for the reference.

Comment: @JayBKim: Yes, specifically IEEE-754 double-precision binary floating point, which is very fast, but imprecise. (Someday maybe JavaScript will have the new [2008] IEEE-754 double-precision *decimal* floating point, like [decimal64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal64_floating-point_format) or decimal128...)